# lightbox accordion conflict

Tags: lightbox, accordion, conflict

i have a page with 3 scripts: idTabs, lightbox ( from dreamweaver) and accordion(also from dreamweaver) . I made some tests: lightbox doesnt work with accordion. each of them alone works fine, but combined accordion crashes, doesn't work and lightbox works. 
here is some code :

> ```
> <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
> <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>
> <script src="jquery-ui-1.7.2/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script src="jquery-ui-1.7.2/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript>
>
> </script>
> <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script src="scripts/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <link href="jquery-ui-1.7.2/css/base/ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> <link href="jquery-ui-1.7.2/css/base/ui.accordion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> <link href="jquery-ui-1.7.2/css/base/ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> <link href="jquery-ui-1.7.2/css/base/ui.images.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
>
>  <script type="text/xml">
>  <!--
>  <oa:widgets>
>    <oa:widget wid="2028523" binding="#jQueryUIAccordion" />
>    <oa:widget wid="2127022" binding="#gallery" />
>  </oa:widgets>
>  -->
>  </script>
>  <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
>  <link href="css/sample_lightbox_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> ```

this is in `<head>`

this is lightbox

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
// BeginOAWidget_Instance_2127022: #gallery
    $(function(){
        $('#gallery a').lightBox({ 
            imageLoading:           '/images/lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif',        // (string) Path and the name of the loading icon
            imageBtnPrev:           '/images/lightbox/lightbox-btn-prev.gif',           // (string) Path and the name of the prev button image
            imageBtnNext:           '/images/lightbox/lightbox-btn-next.gif',           // (string) Path and the name of the next button image
            imageBtnClose:          '/images/lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif',      // (string) Path and the name of the close btn
            imageBlank:             '/images/lightbox/lightbox-blank.gif',          // (string) Path and the name of a blank image (one pixel)
            fixedNavigation:        false,      // (boolean) Boolean that informs if the navigation (next and prev button) will be fixed or not in the interface.
            containerResizeSpeed:   400,             // Specify the resize duration of container image. These number are miliseconds. 400 is default.
            overlayBgColor:         "#999999",      // (string) Background color to overlay; inform a hexadecimal value like: #RRGGBB. Where RR, GG, and BB are the hexadecimal values for the red, green, and blue values of the color.
            overlayOpacity:         .6,     // (integer) Opacity value to overlay; inform: 0.X. Where X are number from 0 to 9
            txtImage:               'Image',                //Default text of image
            txtOf:                  'of'
        });
    });

// EndOAWidget_Instance_2127022
      </script>
```

this is the accordion

> ```
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>     // BeginOAWidget_Instance_2028523: #jQueryUIAccordion
>      $(function(){
>                   // Accordion
>                   $("#jQueryUIAccordion").accordion({ header: "h3",
>                                           >           animated: "slide",
>     event: "click",
>     collapsible : "false"
>     });         
>             });
>
>     // EndOAWidget_Instance_2028523
>             </script>
>             <!-- Accordion -->
>             <div id="jQueryUIAccordion" class="ui-gray-icons  ">
>               <div>
>                 <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
>                 <div> Vivamus rutrum, sapien ac fermentum imperdiet, nisi libero mattis quam, eu mollis sem metus id ligula. </div>
>               </div>
>               <div>
>                 <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
>                 <div>it, tristique egestas erat interdum id.</div>
>               </div>
>               <div>
>                 <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
>                 <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
>               </div>
> ```

I hope I haven't lost you.  I want to underline that I made no modifications to the scripts ! they are the same as I added from dreamweaver. THANK YOu !

UPDATE: i solved the problem. For other users who have this problem, just DELETE the jquery from lightbox, the jquery from accordion will take care of both lightbox and accordion ! it can be closed

LATER UPDATE. i observed that only opera loads OK accordion and lightbox. firefox doesnt load accordion and lightbox at all. this is the console errors :
[12:56:53.907] $("#jQueryUIAccordion").accordion is not a function @ http://localhost/SITE/incercare3.php#:190
[12:56:53.969] $("#gallery a").lightBox is not a function @ http://localhost/SITE/incercare3.php#:275

chrome also doesnt load the 2 scripts: this are the errors chrome gives me :

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion'
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lightBox'

Opinions ?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you are loading jquery twice times. This will cause conflicts.

Second, I just see lightbox and idTabs scripts included in your header, where is the accordion plugin?

idTabs is bean loaded before jquery, make it loads after jquery.

Take a look in the version of your jQuery, you are using plugins that require jQuery 1.7 and 1.3 at same time, you will have conflict.

Anyway you can use jQuery.noConflict() to use the both versions at same time.

Just a tip for you to studies javascript a bit more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: jquery ui 1.7 is the accordion !

Comment: Ok, but jquery ui uses jQuery 1.3 and you are loadin a newer jquery for you lightbox, it will overload the $ global var, and you will lose the accordion function. In the jquery noConflict docs some other are with the same problem.... Try to load the second javascript instance with noConflict and use a diferent var like $$ for it. Then add the plugins for newer in the new window.$$ that refers newer jQuery